# Is there a function that makes a unique combinations from a list of lists? Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if there is a function that does this.

> let a be something that has two states, such as binary number (either 0 or 1)
>
> ```
> Input = [0,0,0]
> ```
>
> Calculate possible combinations of the bits (total 8)
>
> ```
> Output = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1]...[1,1,1]]
> ```

If there is no such function how to implement it? I'm new to Haskell. Thanks.
I have tried

```
possible :: Int -> [Int]
possible _ = [0, 1]

variations (x:xs) = transpose (map possible (x:xs))
```

But it does not do what I expect

Comment: `replicateM 3 [0,1]`. there should be duplicates...

Comment: @WillNess For a brief moment I thought you were speaking about duplicate elements in the resulting list and I was kind of confused. Then the penny dropped :-)

Comment: sorry for being too terse.

Answer (score 0):

There are two inputs: the available bits `input == [0,1]` and the size of the output combinations `n == 3`.

For each fixed value of `n`, there is a use of `Applicative []` to create a list of *tuples*:

```
-- n == 3
> input = [0,1]
> (,,) <$> input <*> input <*> input
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)]
```

For a list of lists, you can proceed recursively. In the base case of `n == 0`, there is only one way to choose a list of 0 elements:

```
variations 0 input = [[]]
```

For non-zero `n`, you start by getting all the combinations of length `n-1`, and for each one adding one new combination of length `n` for each available bit. As a list comprehension,

```
variations n input = [(x:xs) | x <-input, xs <- variations (n-1) input]
```

Then

```
variations 0 [0,1] == [[]]
variations 1 [0,1] == [[0], [1]]  -- prepend 0 and 1 to []
variations 2 [0,1] == [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]  -- prepend 0 and 1 to each of [0] and [1]
-- etc
```

---

If you want to hard-code the set of available bits and basically just infer the compute the length from your placeholder list, you can write

```
variations xs = if null xs then [[]] else [ (y:ys) | y <- [0,1], ys <- variations (tail xs)]
```

or

```
variations [] = [[]]
variations (_:xs) = [(y:ys) | y <- [0,1], ys <- variations xs]
```